# Can I enter the UK with a temporary EU Spouse sticker, if my passport is full?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, dutch-residents

I'm a US citizen and permanent resident of the Netherlands, and my wife and I have plans to visit the UK over the Christmas holiday. I just discovered that my passport is full, with no room to stamp entry/exit.  I have a Dutch workers permit card (for skilled immigrant workers), as well as a *temporary* sticker in my passport, certifying I am the spouse of an EU citizen (the permanent card should arrive by April).

Will I be able to enter the UK with either of these artifacts?

The info I found online suggests the temporary sticker should be sufficient, but I'm concerned because I was just in Ireland two weeks ago, and the immigration agent there told me it wasn't (this was when I discovered my passport was full).  Of course the rules may differ between Ireland and the UK, or the immigration agent may have been mistaken.  Thus my question.

Comment: Sufficient for what? Avoiding an entry stamp? What happened in Ireland then? Are you concerned that you would be refused entry and forced to turn back because there is no space to stamp your passport?

Comment: @Relaxed: In Ireland, he reluctantly stamped over an existing stamp.  And yes, I'm concerned I might be refused entry.

Comment: Is there an old visa you can remove from your passport?

Comment: @JonathanReez:Hmm, interesting option. And I do have one. Unfortunately, it won't come off.

Comment: Did you end up traveling to UK?

Comment: How did this turn out? It's an unanswered question and we aspire to closing these or whatever.

Comment: @GayotFow I was able to enter, without any problems. But that doesn't really answer the question of whether it's technically permitted, or I could be denied entry if the agent had felt like it, which is why I haven't added my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP himself:

> I was able to enter, without any problems. But that doesn't really
>   answer the question of whether it's technically permitted, or I could
>   be denied entry if the agent had felt like it, which is why I haven't
>   added my own answer.

So the answer is: **maybe**.